# What is the equivalent for the "propfull" shortcut in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, properties, field, shortcut

What is the shortcut for auto-implementing a property in vb.net? I want get/set and associated field, like with "propfull" in C#.

I'm using VS12 with ReSharper 7.1.3

Comment: You can use JustCode extension provided by Telerik ~> http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx

Comment: Type "prope?" and hit Tab twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can declare property just like this without get or set

```
Property Prop2 As String = "Empty"
```

this is equivalent to

```
Private _Prop2 As String = "Empty" 
Property Prop2 As String 
    Get 
        Return _Prop2
    End Get 
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Prop2 = value
    End Set 
End Property
```

here are the details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx